# How to display "loading" after several JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, loading

I created a customized page on a SharePoint list for a new form.
In this customized page, I've a JS function that will load various documents of the document library in a Telerik RadComboBox component.
But I'm getting a lot of documents, the form opens but doesn't give the hand as a whole list of documents isn't charged.
I would like to see a "Loading ..." as this form page is not fully loaded but I can't implement this function.

I've my ASPX form containing my RadCombobox :

```
    <tr>
  <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
      <telerik:RadListBox  id="rdlFilesForDocument" TransferToID="rdlFilesForDocumentDest" runat="server" 
        AllowTransfer="true" Height="200px" Width="210px" ButtonSettings-AreaWidth="35px" OnClientTransferred="onDocumentTransferred" ButtonSettings-ShowTransferAll="False" />
      <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="rdlFilesForDocumentDest" Height="200px" Width="175px" ButtonSettings-AreaWidth="35px" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I've my JS that will filter the documents :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Filter Document list with filter
        function filterDocumentList(sender, e) {
            var rdlFilesForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdlFilesForDocument.ClientID %>");
            var rdcEntityForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcEntityForDocument.ClientID %>");
            var rdcYearForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcYearForDocument.ClientID %>");
            var rdcTypeForLegalDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcTypeForDocument.ClientID %>");
            filterList(rdlFilesForDocumentJS, rdcEntityForDocumentJS, rdcYearForDocumentJS, rdcTypeForDocumentJS);
        }

        //Init combobox and fileslistBoxlist
        function pageLoad() {        
            if (!isPostBack) {
                //Init Document files filter and listbox
                var rdlFilesForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdlFilesForDocument.ClientID %>");
                var rdlFilesForDocumentDestJS = $find("<%= rdlFilesForDocumentDest.ClientID %>");
                var selectDocumentFileFieldResult = $('select[id*=FormField][id*=SelectResult]')[0];
                var rdcEntityForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcEntityForDocument.ClientID %>");
                var rdcYearForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcYearForDocument.ClientID %>");
                var rdcTypeForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcTypeForDocument.ClientID %>");
                initComboBox(rdlFilesForDocumentJS, rdlFilesForDocumentDestJS, selectDocumentFileFieldResult, rdcEntityForDocumentJS, rdcYearForDocumentJS, rdcTypeForDocumentJS, "Documents", entityValue, siteUrl);
            }
            else {
                alert('No Document');
            }
        };
</script>
```

How can I've my "Loading" is displayed as my JS function isn't completed ?

I've test with :

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
   function filterDocumentList(sender, e) {
     //MyFunction....
     }
}); 
Or 
$(document).ready(function()
{
   function filterDocumentList(sender, e) {
     //MyFunction....
     }
});
```

But it isn't working properly and my document list no longer charge...

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like your function ever gets called.  Just use the jQuery function to call filterDocumentList when the page loads and hide your loading message.

```
<div class="loading">
  <h1>Loading</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Filter Document list with filter
function filterDocumentList(sender, e) {
    var rdlFilesForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdlFilesForDocument.ClientID %>");
    var rdcEntityForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcEntityForDocument.ClientID %>");
    var rdcYearForDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcYearForDocument.ClientID %>");
    var rdcTypeForLegalDocumentJS = $find("<%= rdcTypeForDocument.ClientID %>");
    filterList(rdlFilesForDocumentJS, rdcEntityForDocumentJS, rdcYearForDocumentJS, rdcTypeForDocumentJS);
}
$(function() {
    filterDocumentList();
    $('.loading').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've the same thing, the "loading" is displayed only on the form and not when my function JS is finished...
I think having several JS functions can cause this problem...